# I am trying to display specific data by passing a parameter to a fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a component that is a select box, i added an onChange to the select box to "capture" its data and set it to a variable in state. I then try to pass it as props to another component [i.e the "display component"] then i use this.props at the end of a new fetch call in the display component to display the data.........it doesn't work. Please Help.

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        routes: [],
        vessel: ''
    }
    this.makeChange = this.makeChange.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/routes`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            routes: data
        }))
  }

makeChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        vessel: event.target.value
    })
}
render() {

    let { routes } = this.state
    return (
        <>
            <select onChange={this.makeChange}>
                <option>Select A Vessel</option>
                {routes.map(vessel => {
                    return (
                        <option key={uuidv4()}>{vessel.vessel}</option>
                    )
                })}
            </select>

            <VRoute vessel={this.state.vessel} />
        </>
    )
}
```

}
}

-----------------------DISPLAY COMPONENT BELOW-------------------------------

```
class VRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        routes: [],
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/routes/${this.props.vessel}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            routes: data
        }))
} 

render() {
    let { routes } = this.state;
    return ( <table>
      <tbody>
         </tr>
                        {routes.map(value => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                                    <td>{value.departure_port}</td>
                                    <td>{value.arrival_port}</td>
                                    <td>{value.departure_time}</td>
                                    <td>{value.arrival_time}</td>
                                    <td>{value.date_stamp}</td>
                                    <td>{value.price}</td>
                                    <td><button className='delete-btn'>x</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Should `<option key={uuidv4()}>{vessel.vessel}</option>` not be `<option value={uuidv4()}>{vessel.vessel}</option>`?

Comment: When Vroute is mounted the user still not select anything and then when select changes, display component will not fire CDM because is already mounted. To fix this change it to ComponentWillUpdate

Comment: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop..... hence "key" in option

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select onChange={this.makeChange}>
                <option>Select A Vessel</option>
                {routes.map(vessel => {
                    return (
                        <option key={uuidv4()} value={vessel.vessel}>{vessel.vessel}</option>
                    )
                })}
            </select>
            <VRoute vessel={this.state.vessel} />
        </>
```

Display component..

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.vessel !== this.state.vessel) {
    this.setState({vessel: nextProps.vessel}, () => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:5000/routes/${this.state.vessel}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
           routes: data
        }))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adolfo, this does work but it's returning empty arrays, i think it's something with the database...not sure

Comment: Do .then(data => { console.log(data) this.setState({ routes: data }) }. You should see in console the data received from database and check if it's correct.